# Is there a managed way to do P2S VPN in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

I want to connect my (OSX) laptop to a VPC in AWS but I couldn't find a way to do this since I don't have a static IP.

Azure has managed P2S VPN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about. Is there something like this in AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stand up a virtual device (such as a CheckPoint firewall) in the VPC on an EC2 instance that has point to site VPN functionality. There are a number of AMI’s and quick starts for this available. You would also need a VPN client running on your laptop.

As an alternative, you can set up a bastion server and whitelist your IP. You can create a shell script that gets your IP and makes an AWS CLI call to update the security group with that value if it doesn’t exist. Then, log into the bastion and you’re in the VPC.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up setting up an OpenVPN server for this. Hopefully in the future AWS comes out with a managed P2S VPN service.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a client VPN under the VPC menu:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-working-endpoints.html

It will require to have server cert, as well as client certificates or a link to managed AD for authentication.